# How to add One to One relationship with Model first approach

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core

Getting following error while adding migration,

> The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
>   relationship between 'EntityA.EntityB' and 'EntityB.EntityA'. To
>   identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the
>   foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the
>   same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse.

There are some solutions which are suggesting to add foreign key in one of the entity and then use Fluent API.

But as I'm using model first approach and after that I've generated classes, how should I add foreign key to generated class, it will overwrite if I made any changes in future to the same entity.

So I would like to know how to add one to one relationship using model first approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "model first approach"?  That is a term from previous versions of EF that doesn't really apply to EF Core.  But the error is pretty clear.  Add a Foreign Key property to one entity or the other to enable EF Core conventions to determine the dependent side of the relationship, or use a Fluent Configuration.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the reply, so I've added .edmx file, where I've added all entities and relationships, and then used generate code option. So here are you saying that with EF Core, either we can use code first or DB first?

Comment: Yes.  EF Core has no .EDMX.  All model mapping and configuration is embedded in your code (Conventions, Annotations, and Fluent Configuration).  You can generate the code from an existing database, generate the database from code, or manage each of them independently.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks, can you add this as an answer, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core has no .EDMX. All model mapping and configuration is embedded in your code (Conventions, Annotations, and Fluent Configuration). You can generate the code from an existing database, generate the database from code, or manage each of them independently.

But the error is pretty clear. Add a Foreign Key property to one entity or the other to enable EF Core conventions to determine the dependent side of the relationship, or use a Fluent Configuration.